# How to Insert a Graph in Tkinter Using Formula in Script

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
def process():
    import matplotlib
    import Tkinter as tk

    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
    # from matplotlib import style
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure


    class GraphPage(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.title_label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page Example")
            self.title_label.pack()
            self.pack()

        def add_mpl_figure(self, fig):
            self.mpl_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
            self.mpl_canvas.show()
            self.mpl_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.mpl_canvas, self)
            self.toolbar.update()
            self.mpl_canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


    class MPLGraph(Figure):

      def __init__(self):
            Figure.__init__(self, figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
            self.plot = self.add_subplot(111)
            self.plot.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 6])#####here i need to add values in which are calculated in form  line 113,119,125 and 140 but i am not able to do


    fig = MPLGraph()

    root = tk.Tk()
    graph_page = GraphPage(root)
    graph_page.add_mpl_figure(fig)

    root.mainloop()
```

So I have the formula and variables above this code, but if I add those variables here, it says variables are not defined.

Comment: Create a [mcve] - this is not **minimal**.

Comment: what **those** variables ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: I tried code and it works for me without problems. Maybe problem is because you assing to local value `fig = MPLGraph()` so you can't have access to `fig.plot` outside function. You should show how you try to add values to plot.